# Rewrite rule breaking rewrite conditions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I created an MVC application in a subfolder. Here is to directory map:

```
Root
   -MVC
    --.htaccess
    --index.php
    --App
        ---Controller
        ---Core
        ---Model
        ---Route
        ---Service
        ---View
        ---application.init.php
    --Public
        ---css
        ---img
        ---script
        ---404.html
        ---index.php
        ---.htaccess
```

I created the original public/.htaccess file to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /MVC/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It worked, but I did not like having the 'public' folder show in the url, so I deleted the contents of the public/.htaccess and moved it to the MVC/.htaccess and modified it to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /MVC/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+) public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The MVC application itself still works, but none of my rewrite conditions do, so I can't access any css files, images, etc.

Comment: why don't you just point your server to {...}/MVC/public instead of {...}/MVC

Comment: There are multiple applications on the server.

Comment: Maybe its worth using a subdomain instead?

Comment: Can't use a subdomain. I don't have access to do that.